# The Interface at HebrewBooks.org

Tags: jewish-books, internet, how-to

When I load a page at [Hebrew Books](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19344&st=&pgnum=4), the text appears on screen, for less than one second, in a computer font which is then replaced by an image of the printed page in which the characters coincide neatly. I assume that this reflects the technology that allows electronic searches within the text that highlight the relevant places on the image of the printed page.

But the printed page is often harder to read, in a kind of blurry or broken Rashi script. I find the computer font much easier reading.

Is there any way to get the display to remain on the computer font, either on Hebrew Books or on another comparable website?

Comment: What an interesting observation. It happens for me too. There is a button top right of the page where you can "Add Feedback on this Sefer". I suggest you ask the question there. I'm afraid that here I agree with those who say it is off topic.

Comment: I just printed a page from Sha"s and another from *Mikra'ot Gedolot". Had no problems. An idea. There is a link to download the whole file as a PDF. I know some of these files occupy lots of space. But, it may be worth a try and then you should be able to print the desired pages from the PDF file, then delete the file, afterwards.

Comment: You can switch the formatting over to computer text on the Shas on HebrewBooks, but AFAIK you can't on anything else.

Comment: try the new betahebrewbooks, who was improved one week ago

Comment: I know how to do it for Shas (click the "Text" button on the upper left-hand corner, or edit the URL) to get http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=2&format=text, but I don't know about other books on the website.

Comment: @Chaim What you were seeing was the page loading slowly. (Do you have a sluggish internet connection?). Text loads faster than images, so the OCR-ed text of the PDF showed up first, and then the image loaded afterwards. I never noticed this on HebrewBooks until today, when my internet was (is) slow, that it loaded like that.

Comment: The discussion about whether this question is on topic has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62249/discussion-on-question-by-chaim-the-interface-at-hebrewbooks-org).

Answer (score -1):

I haven't encountered any problems printing the page that you had in your link. One idea that may work for you is to download the entire file. It usually downloads as a PDF. If you then open the file in PDF reader, it should render the font properly, and you should be able to print from there. I just tried this, and I had no problems. Mind you, the scanned quality is not the greatest, but it is readable and represents what's on the screen.

One thing you can try in the PDF reader is adjusting the scaling and / or the grey scale and some other settings. Maybe, that will fix the problem. Beyond that, there may be some other problem with your computer configuration that would leave us guessing, I'm afraid.

You may want to pose your problem directly to them. If you click "about" on top of the home page, then click the "Feedback Form" on the bottom of the About page, you should be able to submit your question.

Please post any answers that you may get from them.

Comment: In the example page linked to in the question, the letters on the left side are compressed and distorted as a result of how the physical book was copied or scanned. Does opening that page in a PDF reader correct for that? (I doubt it.) I think that's the type of issue Chaim is trying to solve.

Comment: @IsaacMoses See my latest edits. I had no problems.

Comment: It may be better to copy-paste the words. That's probably the easiest way to get the OCR text that the OP wants. (You should probably [edit] to include that option in your answer.)

Comment: @Shokhet Usually, you cannot copy an image-rendered PDF. The page OP linked to has Rash"i letters. I don't think such letters are part of the UTF-8 letter standard where they would be recognized as valid letters.

Comment: Yeah. The particular sefer that the OP is after has a barely usable OCR; I tried copying some text from the page he linked to. A lot of it did come through, though, just not enough to make that option easier than typing it all out from scratch. Other seforim, even many with Rashi lettering, have better copyable plaintext.